# Sorbet not finding `has_many` association methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sorbet

I have a Rails model which `has_many` `items`:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  extend T::Sig

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  before_save do
    # hyper simple test method to illustrat problem
    puts items
  end
end
```

However Sorbet can't seem to relate to the `has_many :items`. When I run Sorbet typechecking I get the following error:

```
$ srb tc
app/models/plan.rb:11: Method items does not exist on T.class_of(Plan) https://srb.help/7003
    11 |    items
            ^^^^^
  Did you mean:
    sorbet/rails-rbi/models/plan.rbi:86: Plan::GeneratedAssociationMethods#items
    86 |  def items; end
```

The answer to Sorbet's question is yes - I do mean that method. Where is the confusion coming from? Why doesn't the definition of `.items` in the RBI file satisfy Sorbet's need to know where this method is defined?

Comment: I have never had occasion to use sorbet so I apologize for my naivety; however have you tried using [`sorbet-rails`](https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/sorbet-rails)? Rails is a monster all of its own and many gems that work in standard ruby need a little additional help to work correctly in the rails cosmic magic atmosphere.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I already have that installed but it sadly yields no dice

Comment: @engineersmnky - I solved it in the end. You may be interested to see the answer - after 10 years of developing in Rails I'm kind of surprised I didn't already know this!

Answer (score 4):

Ok so this turned out to be a misunderstanding of Rails (Ruby?) rather than Sorbet. Skipping ahead this is actually a point to sorbet because it helped spot and solve this problem.

The problem is that when you pass a block to `before_save`, the block gets called on the class (`Plan`), not the instance (`plan`). Instead, an instance is passed into it.

So taking the original code:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  extend T::Sig

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  before_save do
    # hyper simple test method to illustrate problem
    puts items
  end
end
```

This would result in the execution of `Plan.before_save(plan)`. Where `plan` is the instance of `Plan`. So in the example above, `items` is being pulled out of thin air and won't work.

### Two syntaxes which do work

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  extend T::Sig

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  before_save do |plan| # <= notice the argument
    puts plan.items
  end
end
```

will work. And so will:

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  extend T::Sig

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
  before_save :put_items

  def put_items
    puts items
  end
end
```

I'm not quite sure what makes the second one work, whether it's Ruby magic or Rails magic but sometimes there's just too much magic for my liking.

Comment: This is likely due to lexical scope and implicit self. `sorbet` probably does not (and cannot) recognize that inside the `before_save` the block is executed in the context of the instance of the class where `self` (implicit) is said instance. Instead it assumes this block is executed in the context of the class instance itself. The block argument and explicit receiver appears to change this notion. In the second form `sorbet` recognizes that `put_items` is an instance method and evaluates in that context.

Comment: So it's actually Sorbet's problem in a way. Maybe they prefer to report a false positive in this instance; the alternative is for them to not type check blocks because you can't know the context the block will run on

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is the proc passed to `before_save` is run in the context of an instance of the class rather than the class itself which Sorbet isn't able to understand by default. Sorbet provides [`T.bind`](https://sorbet.org/docs/type-assertions#tbind) for this case which allows you to tell Sorbet to treat `self` as a different type within the block

```rb
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  extend T::Sig

  has_many :items, dependent: :destroy

  before_save do
    T.bind(self, Plan) # treats `self` as `Plan` instead of `T.class_of(Plan)`
    
    # hyper simple test method to illustrate problem
    puts items # type-checks fine
  end
end
```